# Limit the length of multiple UITextFields

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have four `UITextField`s, and would like to limit the length of each one, but they are all different lengths. I have the following code so far, but it doesn't quite work correctly

```
define MAXLENGTH 5
define MAXQTY 3
define MAXSIZE 4
define MAXBRAND 10

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    int lengtha = [brand.text length] ;
    NSLog(@"lenghta = %d",lengtha);
    if (lengtha >= MAXBRAND && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
    brand.text = [brand.text substringToIndex:MAXBRAND];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;

    int lengthb = [qty.text length] ;
    NSLog(@"lenghtb = %d",lengtha);
    if (lengthb >= MAXQTY && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        qty.text = [qty.text substringToIndex:MAXQTY];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;

    int lengthc = [size.text length] ;
    NSLog(@"lenghtc = %d",lengtha);
    if (lengthc >= MAXSIZE && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        size.text = [size.text substringToIndex:MAXSIZE];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;

    int lengthd = [price.text length] ;
    NSLog(@"lenghtd = %d",lengtha);
    if (lengthd >= MAXLENGTH && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        price.text = [price.text substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: As soon as your code reaches the first "return YES;" after the if statement, nothing else get process.  Your logic is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If brand, qty, size and price are instance variables (or properties) and are connected to your UITextFields you could try this:

```
define MAXLENGTH 5
define MAXQTY 3
define MAXSIZE 4
define MAXBRAND 10

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if (textField == brand) {
        int lengtha = [brand.text length];
        NSLog(@"lenghta = %d",lengtha);
        if (lengtha >= MAXBRAND && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
            brand.text = [brand.text substringToIndex:MAXBRAND];
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    } else if (textField == qty) {
        int lengthb = [qty.text length];
        NSLog(@"lenghtb = %d",lengthb);
        if (lengthb >= MAXQTY && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
            qty.text = [qty.text substringToIndex:MAXQTY];
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    } else if (textField == size) {
        int lengthc = [size.text length];
        NSLog(@"lenghtc = %d",lengthc);
        if (lengthc >= MAXSIZE && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
            size.text = [size.text substringToIndex:MAXSIZE];
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    } else if (textField == price) {
        int lengthd = [price.text length];
        NSLog(@"lenghtd = %d",lengthd);
        if (lengthd >= MAXLENGTH && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
            price.text = [price.text substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH];
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have amended the code as per your suggestion, and I am still getting the same result, There is no limit it the textfield and NSLog is not reporting the character count. 
I have the UITextfields all set up in the .h file and the IBOutlets also in the .h file

Comment: I have fixed it your code is great, I have added brand.delegate=self under viewDidLoad and it works great now, thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, you have to set the delegate for all four UITextFields. Also I edited my code above a little bit. You were always NSLogging lengtha in all four cases instead of using the correct variable each time (lengtha, lengthb, lengthc, lengthd).